# Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string - get dropdown list to dynamical display data

Tags: php, dropdown

I'm pretty new to PHP and I'm stuck on on this last bit of code. its coming up with the below error and I'm not sure how to fix it.

> Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string in
>   /home/e0753906/public_html/test4.php on line 70

I'm try to get the data in my database to display in a table once the selected date have been chosen from the dropdown list. the Date chosen in the dropdown list need to be the date in the WHERE clause.

my php file looks like this:

```
<?php
// set up database global variables
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "e0753906_Sam";
        $password = "Tamara1623";

//connect to the database           
try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $GLOBALS['servername'] . 
  ";dbname=e0753906_OaktownFootball", $GLOBALS['username'], 
  $GLOBALS['password']);
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
   }
  catch(PDOException $e) {
      echo "An error occured: " . $e->getMessage();
}

// global variables
$query = $conn->query('SELECT DISTINCT `Date` FROM Fixtures');

$data = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM Fixtures'); 

$test = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM Fixtures WHERE `Date`=20160709');   

$data_s = $conn->query('SELECT Date, 
                      (SELECT Team_Name FROM Teams WHERE Teams.Team_ID = 
                      Home_team.Team_ID) As Home_Team,
                      (SELECT Team_Name FROM Teams WHERE Teams.Team_ID = 
                      Away_team.Team_ID) As Away_Team,
                        Home_Score,
                        Away_Score
                        FROM Fixtures
                        JOIN Home_team ON Home_team.Home_Team_ID = 
                        Fixtures.Home_Team_ID
                        JOIN Away_team ON Away_team.Away_Team_ID = 
                        Fixtures.Away_Team_ID');

?>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Oaktown Football Club</title>
 </head>
 <body>

<form action="test2.php" method="get">
  <select name="Date">
    <option>Choose a date</option>
        <?php foreach ($query->fetchAll() as $Fixtures):?>
            <option name="Date" value="<?php echo $Fixtures['Date'];?>">
            <?php echo $Fixtures['Date'];?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Show details">
</form>
<?php
echo "<table border=1>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Home Team</th>
            <th>Away Team</th>
            <th>Score</th>
        </tr>" ;
         if (isset($_GET['Date'])) {

                    ob_start();
                    echo $_GET['Date']; 
                    $datetest = ob_get_contents();

                    $fixture = "
                    {$data_s}
                    WHERE `Date` = ' . $datatest . '";

                    while($records = $fixture->fetch()) {
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>" . $records['Date'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $records['Home_Team'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $records['Away_Team'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $records['Home_Score'] . "-" . 
                        $records['Away_Score'] . "</td>";
                        echo "</tr>";} 
} 
echo "</table>" ?>

</body>
```

Thanks

I have also tried

```
//Get data from date    
if (isset($_GET['Date'])) {
    $dateQuery = "
    {$data}
    WHERE `Date` = :date";

$date = $conn->prepare($dateQuery);

$date->execute(['date'=>$_GET['Date']]);


$selectedDate = $date->fetch(POD::FETCH_ASSOC);

var_dump($selectedDate);};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set `$data_s`, this is the result of executing a query, so in the line..

```
            $fixture = "
            {$data_s}
            WHERE `Date` = ' . $datatest . '";
```

Your trying to add the result of executing the query into the string.  As I think your just trying to add the `WHERE` clause onto the end of this statement, I think you can just need to set `$data_s` to...

```
$data_s = 'SELECT Date,
                      (SELECT Team_Name FROM Teams WHERE Teams.Team_ID =
                      Home_team.Team_ID) As Home_Team,
                      (SELECT Team_Name FROM Teams WHERE Teams.Team_ID =
                      Away_team.Team_ID) As Away_Team,
                        Home_Score,
                        Away_Score
                        FROM Fixtures
                        JOIN Home_team ON Home_team.Home_Team_ID =
                        Fixtures.Home_Team_ID
                        JOIN Away_team ON Away_team.Away_Team_ID =
                        Fixtures.Away_Team_ID';
```

But I'm also not sure about ...

```
            ob_start();
            echo $_GET['Date']; 
            $datetest = ob_get_contents();
```

You could remove this and just use ...

```
            $fixture = "
            {$data_s}
            WHERE `Date` = ' . $_GET['Date'] . '";
```

**Update:**
As this now doesn't execute the query, you need to do it here...

```
    $fixture = $conn->query("{$data_s}
        WHERE `Date` = '".$_GET['Date']}."'");
    if ( $fixture === false ) {
       die ($conn->error);
    }
```

Comment: I still seem to be having problems, the error now says, Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object .                                                                               Also the ' . $GET['Date'] . ' doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Updated answer - it wasn't running the query.

Comment: Updated the ` $GET['Date']` bit as well.

Comment: I'm still getting error's, it's either saying unexpected '$_GET' or unexpected " not matter what I try it just wont work.

Comment: It would help if you said what the errors are.  I've updated the code at the end to add the date in differently, but also to display an error if this fails.

Comment: it doesn't come up with an error, it just come up with the dropdown box, but no date are displaying in it.

Comment: on inspection I can see:    Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object in /home/e0753906/public_html/test4.php on line 43  - don't understand why it's affecting the dropdown box considering that was working fine and the new code if after the dropdown coding.

Comment: OMG it's working. not sure what happen before, but it's working now.

Comment: Thank you so much ... Thank you...Thank you. Life safer. I have been pulling my hair out for weeks with this problem.